# Why redis respond nil to ping?

Tags: ssl, redis, digital-ocean

I have access to two instances of Redis.

1. Connected locally with `redis-cli`, when I `ping` I get the response `PONG`

   ```
   127.0.0.1:6379> ping
   PONG
   ```
2. Managed by Digital Ocean connected by `redli` with `--tls` option, when I `ping` I get `nil`:

   ```
   Connected to 5.0.9
   > ping
   nil
   ```

What does it mean? It is a problem with `redli`, Digital Ocean, TLS, Redis version? Why do I get different responses? How can I debug this problem?

- Logs from Digital Ocean:

[image]

- other queries like `echo "Hello"` also have `nil` response.

Comment: what does `ping "hello"` return?

Comment: also nil, I created ticked on Digital Ocean, if anyone will meet a problem like this, I will attach there a response from support.

Comment: well, did you `AUTH` to your digital ocean redli instance?

Comment: on AUTH I have nill too, anyway I am pasting the password in connecting command.